# Why is mousemove returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I use mousemove and when i going down and up my e.layerY is undefined.
scroll nie zostal 232 
scroll undefined

This is for html, javascript.

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let topCanvas = canvas.offsetTop;
let leftCanvas = canvas.offsetLeft;
var mouseDown = false;

$(document).dblclick(function(e) {
  mouseDown = true;
  $(document).mousemove(poruszmysza);
});

function poruszmysza(e) {
  if (mouseDown == true) {
    console.log("not considering scroll position");
    console.log("scroll nie zostal", e.clientY - topCanvas);
    console.log("considering scroll position");
    console.log("scroll", e.layerY);
  }
}
```

I expect the same result, but I have `undefined`.

Comment: The event object passed to `mousemove` handler does not have such property as `layerY`, see "common event properties" chapter of [documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: Provide a [mcve]